# How to go forward in smart wizard after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, smart-wizard

I want to go to the next step if the ajax call is successful, but i am not able to call the smart wizard methods inside the ajax call. My code is here.

```
var wizard = $("#listing_wizard").smartWizard({onLeaveStep:stepSubmit});

    //stepsubmit
    function stepSubmit(){
      var that = this;
      //that.goForward  ------- working here
      var step_no = this.curStepIdx+1;
      var form_data = $("#step_"+step_no+"_form").serialize();

      $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:"<?php echo URL_ADMIN ?>ajax.php",
        data:form_data,
        success:function(data){
          return that.goForward; //not working here
        }
      });
    }
```

[I think the problem is here in these "this" so how can I call the smart wizard this.goForward after ajax call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svb6F.png)

Comment: Ummmm `that.goForward();` missing parentheses?

Comment: Tried that, but not working either, instead, that was causing unlimited ajax calls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the latest [Smart Wizard v4](https://github.com/techlab/SmartWizard), here is the workaround.

```js
$('#listing_wizard').smartWizard();

$("#listing_wizard").on("leaveStep", function(e, anchorObject, stepNumber, stepDirection) {

  var form_data = $("#step_"+ stepNumber +"_form").serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:"<?php echo URL_ADMIN ?>ajax.php",
    data:form_data,
    success:function(data){
       // indicate the ajax has been done, release the next step
       $("#listing_wizard").smartWizard("next");
    }
  });

  // Return false to cancel the `leaveStep` event 
  // and so the navigation to next step which is handled inside success callback.
  return false;

});
```

This is already addressed on [How to wait ajax done to process next step?](https://github.com/techlab/SmartWizard/issues/20)
Also refer the documentation [jQuery Smart Wizard 4: Documentation](http://techlaboratory.net/smartwizard/documentation)

Comment: I am using v3 but let me try this

Comment: I have updated to v4 and Now I am able to submit each step via ajax. Thanks for the help

Comment: Using jquery.wizard and this logic (return false, have ajax move the step) def helped. Thanks!